# How to limit an CLI argument to an enum?

Tags: enums, rust

While learning Rust and in an attempt to do something useful, I'm looking to craft a [SAFE API call for DNS:Add service](https://api.safedev.org/dns/add-service.html).
The API is well defined and should by rights be a simple PUT request, the body of which is a number of strings and one variable that is limited to two options.

I've looked to define a struct and enum for the body of the put with its real limits, rather than just using strings; as I expect defining close the reality, is better practice.

I think I must be close but then have a mismatch, trying to limit input to an enum. The third argument should be only 'drive' or 'app' as `RootPathVariant`.

So, I'm looking to assign the `root_path` with a match of `arguments=arg[2]`
but atm the left-side of the match is `&'static str`, which is wrong where it wants a `String`.

## enum is defined:

```
pub enum RootPathVariant { App, Drive }

impl RootPathVariant {
    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            &RootPathVariant::App => "app",
            &RootPathVariant::Drive => "drive",
        }
    }
}
```

## How should I put the left side of this match, to only accept content of that enum?

```
let mut root_path: RootPathVariant = RootPathVariant::Drive;
match args[2].to_string() {
    "drive" => { root_path = RootPathVariant::Drive },
    "app" => { root_path = RootPathVariant::App },
    _ => { println!( "Error: root_path not [drive | app]");  return }
};

let put_body = AddServiceBody {
    long_Name: args[0],
    service_Name: args[1],
    root_Path: root_path,
    service_Home_Dir_Path: args[3]
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use `string.as_ref()` to get `&str` from a `String` and then use it in a match. But what is the type of `args`? `to_string()` may be unnecessary if you already have `&str`.

Comment: Please add the exact error message and a [MCVE]. Then you are more likely to get any answers :)

Comment: @Pavel Strakhov the type of args follows simple from Cargo:getopts as a Vec<String>. I missed the obvious option to `match args[2].as_str()` which appears to work!

Comment: I'm seconding @LukasKalbertodt's point about an MCVE. For example, this question has *nothing* to do with an enum. I'd bet that [your code looks like this](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=2707ee26ba9429582a72fbed55b7a9e5&version=stable).

Answer (score 1):

Noting the answer looks to be to `match args[2].as_str()`!